# Get a file's last modified date in VB6

Tags: vb6

How do you get any file's last modified date using VB6?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a built in VB6 function for that - no need for FSO (although FSO is great for more advanced file operations)

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262740%28VS.60%29.aspx

```
Dim MyStamp As Date
MyStamp = FileDateTime("C:\TESTFILE.txt")
```

Comment: +1. I recommend avoiding FileSystemObject if possible. It's not always present on user machines. We had a helpdesk problem last month because a paranoid IT department had crippled FileSystemObject, and that broke some software we maintain. Here the native VB6 technique is one line, and the FSO code is at least 3 lines.

Answer (score 3):

Add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (Project->References...) and use the following code:

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fil As File

Set fil = fso.GetFile("C:\foo.txt")
Debug.Print fil.DateLastModified
```

Comment: -1. I recommend avoiding FileSystemObject if possible. It's not always present on user machines. We had a helpdesk problem last month because a paranoid IT department had crippled FileSystemObject, and that broke some software we maintain. Also this can be done in one line in native VB6: must be better than 4 lines with FileSystemObject.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely the easiest way to achieve what you are looking for.

```
Dim myString as String

Dim myDate As Date

myString = Format(FileDateTime("C:\TESTFILE.txt"), "dd-MM-yyyy")

myDate = MyString
```

If you dim your variable as a string, you can use the Format function to shorten the result to just the date.

If you need your variable to be declared as a Date then do as I have done above and declare that as a separate variable. Once the Format function has done its job, copy the String variable to the Date variable and you're done in two lines of code.

As simple as that.

Comment: A good answer. But note the question was asked over 10 years ago ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FileSystemObject here's an [example](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13807)

You can also check out the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sheydkke%28VS.85%29.aspx) the samples are for scripting but they should be translatable to VB6 easily.

Comment: -1. I recommend avoiding FileSystemObject if possible. It's not always present on user machines. We had a helpdesk problem last month because a paranoid IT department had crippled FileSystemObject, and that broke some software we maintain. Also this can be done in one line in native VB6, not 4 lines of FileSystemObject.

Comment: I agree with @MarkJ: avoid FSO wherever possible. If you think VB lacks certain functionality, that's what the Win32 API is for. [Here's a file date/time exmaple](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/fileapi/filedatetime.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the windows api call:
http://www.ex-designz.net/apidetail.asp?api_id=128

Then you can get either creation date or last modified date.

Answer (score 0):

I use this native code to update the date-modified in VB6:

```
Dim nUnit As Integer
nUnit = FreeFile
Open "C:\file.txt" For Append As nUnit
Print #nUnit, ""
Close #nUnit
```

It's has a similar efect to Linux 'touch' command.